# Firebase trigger on current time

Tags: firebase

I create something like calendar with events.
I want to popup message for user when the event come up.

My solution:

```
//this code runs in loop
var offsetRef = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio-demo.com/.info/serverTimeOffset");
offsetRef.on("value", function(snap) {
    var offset = snap.val();
    var estimatedServerTimeMs = new Date().getTime() + offset;
    fbRef.endAt(estimatedServerTimeMs).once("value", function(ss) {/*remove old events*/});
});
```

Is´t possible something like this (without loop)?

```
fbRef.endAt(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP).on("child_added", function(snap) {/*...*/});
```

Thank you for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to calculate the serverTimeOffset just once, and then wrap the popup in a setTimeout after you know what the current time (approximately) is:

```
var timeouts = [];
offsetRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  // Cancel all previous timeouts.
  timeouts.forEach(function(i) { clearTimeout(i); });
  var estTime = new Date().getTime() + snap.val();
  var promptTime = /* Get time at which you want to prompt */
  timeouts.push(setTimeout(function showPrompt() {
    ...
  }, promptTime));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I don´t understand how i combinate your code wih mine? :(


For me is important this line:
fbRef.endAt(estTime).once("value", function(ss) {/*remove old events*/});

How or where can I get events from firebase in your code?
Thanks

Comment: You can always run endAt(estTime).once(...) separately to remove old events. My code snippet only deals with creating a prompt for events in the future.